# Need help setting up 2 Audio Feed inputs with two seperate auto outputs.

Tags: audio, devices

I'm using Scanner Cast and was needing help trying to find the best way to have two different scanner audio feeds that can be uploaded to two scanner cast feeds without each hearing the other. Right now I keep getting both feeds over both outputs at the same time using VB-Audio. I have one audio entering the rear of the PC and the other through the MIC input on the front. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Scanner Cast, and the operation of that particular software is likely off topic here, however, at the most basic level, to do independent audio streams you need software that will allow you to do multiple streams (or run multiple copies) and also allow you to select the particular input to use.

Generally, this looks like setting up two instances of whatever streaming software you are using and configuring one instance to point to one input and the other to point to the other.  VB-Audio would be completely unnecessary.  VB-Audio is only needed if you want to combine two inputs in to one.